# javascript How can I input on different textboxes using buttons (I can only input on decimal textbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use my buttons to put value on other textboxes. 
I can only put on 1 textbox (decimal) and how can I disable other buttons if I dont want it clickable when they are using hexa, binary, and octal.

How can I ignore other input or delete it so it wont ruin my conversion.

Javascript:

```
function showme(count) {

  document.getElementById('dec').value += count;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id='dec' onclick="clickdecimal();" onkeyup="fromdecimal();" type="text">Decimal
<input id='bin' onclick="clickbinary();" onkeyup="frombinary();" type="text">Binary
<input id='hex' onclick="clickhexadecimal();" onkeyup="fromhexadecimal();" type="text">Hexadecimal
<input id='oct' onclick="clickoctal();" onkeyup="fromoctal();" type="text">Octal
<input id='btn' onclick="showme('1'), fromdecimal(), frombinary(), fromhexadecimal(), fromoctal();" type="button" value="1">
```

Comment: I cant put it all.. I dont know why.. I just need to know how to put value on different text boxes using button..

Answer (score 1):

Put these buttons inside a div and show them when the desired field is get focused:

```js
function showme(count) {
  document.getElementById('dec').value += count;
}

function showButtons(){
  document.getElementById('buttons').style.display="block";
}

function hideButtons(){
  document.getElementById('buttons').style.display="none";
}
```

```css
#buttons{display:none}
```

```html
<input onfocus="showButtons()" onfocusout="hideButtons()" onclick="clickdecimal();" onkeyup="fromdecimal();" type="text" id='dec' />Decimal<br/><br/>
<input onclick="clickbinary();" onkeyup="frombinary();" type="text" id='bin' />Binary<br/><br/>
<input onclick="clickhexadecimal();" onkeyup="fromhexadecimal();" type="text" id='hex' />Hexadecimal<br/><br/>
<input onclick="clickoctal();" onkeyup="fromoctal();" type="text" id='oct' />Octal<br/><br/>
<hr>

<div id="buttons">
 <input type="button" onclick="showme('1'), fromdecimal(), frombinary(), fromhexadecimal(), fromoctal();" value="1" id='btn' />
 <input type="button" onclick="showme('2'), fromdecimal(), frombinary(), fromhexadecimal(), fromoctal();" value="2" id='btn' />
 <input type="button" onclick="showme('3'), fromdecimal(), frombinary(), fromhexadecimal(), fromoctal();" value="3" id='btn' /><br/>
 <input type="button" onclick="showme('0'), fromdecimal(), frombinary(), fromhexadecimal(), fromoctal();" value="0" id='btn' />
</div>
```

You may use **Jquery Toggle** to minimize raw JS functions to `elem.toggle()`.